# Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery(…)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, require

I'm trying to load a plugin that needs jquery to work [jquery.countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/)

I was getting this error when calling the plugin on my init class:

> GET http://localhost:3008/js/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)
>
> require.js:166 Uncaught Error: Script error for: jquery(…)

This was my starting code:

```
    define(function (require) {
    var commons = require('commons'), 
    core = require('core/core_library'),
    $ = require('vendor/jquery'),
    ButtonStatus = require('module-pf/ButtonStatus'),
    Archive = require('module-pf/Archive'),
    Countdown = require('appvendor/jquerycountdown');

    });
```

So I started investigating. First, the jquery.countdown library os correctly loaded , as debug says:

[image: Countdown correctly loaded]

So I guessed `require` doesn't know the loading order of those libraries. After some research, I saw that you can just nest dependencies to order them:

```
  define(['commons'], function () {
  require(['vendor/jquery'], function (commons) {

    //Added this for testing by calling jquerycountdown internal funcionality

    require(['appvendor/jquerycountdown'], function (inyectedCountdown) {
      $('#timer').countdown('2020/10/10', function (event) {
        $(this).html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
      });
    });
  });
});
```

But I still get the same error. I have no idea what is happening, maybe incompatible jquery versions? I added that library manually. Jquery is working fine in my project but it is loading two instances, one located in js/jquery (404) and the second one in vendor/js/jquery (200).

Comment: jquery.js isn't being loaded - the URL you're giving is returning a 404

Comment: `http://localhost:3008/js/jquery.js 404 (Not Found)` this is the only important fact here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

Inside `jquerycountdown`library we found a define calling jquery:

```
    define([ "jquery" ], factory);
```

So I just added `vendor/jquery`.